# Вставить код языка в URL

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

интересует такой вопрос можно ли вставлять в URL код языка посредством плагина на WordPress?
Например есть сайт site.by/boom/ он на английском языке, а если я переключаю язык на русский, то URL меняется на site.by/ru/boom/
Принципиально чтобы код языка шёл сразу после домена как в примере.
Если кто знает какие-нибудь решения, подскажите пожалуйста, буду очень благодарен)

Comment: WPML это делает.

Comment: Можно ссылку на скачивание плагина и где в настройках это можно сделать?

Comment: wpml.org - плагин платный. в настройках Languages -> Language URL Format

Answer (score 0):

Для реализации мутиязычности существует масса плагинов.

Платный [WPML](https://wpml.org/ru/).
Бесплатные:   [Polylang](https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/) (аналог WPML), [WP Multilang](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-multilang/), [WPGlobus](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpglobus/) и  [другие](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/multilingual/)